# Flask Monitoring Dashboard not working with after_request

Tags: python, flask, content-security-policy

Flask Monitoring Dashboard Module is not working fine when @app.after_request is used in Flask Server.

If I remove the @app.after_request then the Dashboard is working fine.

I want to include few things in @app.after_request .

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    s= 'request:'+str(request.data)+" \n "+str(request.remote_addr)+"  "+str(request.method)+"  "+ str(request.scheme)+"  "+ str(request.full_path)+"  "+str(response.status)+" \n "+"response returned :"+ str(response.data)
    print(s)
    debugPrint(str(inspect.stack()[0][3]),s)
    response.headers['Strict-Transport-Security'] = 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
    response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self'"
    response.headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = 'nosniff'
    response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
    response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = '1; mode=block'

    return response
```

when this code is included, the flask monitoring Dashboard is showing

[image: Flask Dashboard]

Console Log when I am checking Flask Monitoring Dashboard

[image: Console Log]

Kindly please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Adding Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self' is restrictive and might block a few requests.

Answer (score 0):

As @Halvor Sakshaug observes above, your problem is the line:

```
    response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self'"
```

If you look into your page console you'll see a bunch of messages of the form:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to load the script 'https://unpkg.com/sunburst-chart' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Since the external URLs are loading critical resources (e.g. Angular), and your desired content policy prevents this, at the moment it is only by relaxing your content security policy that you can make the Flask Monitoring Dashboard work.

A line that allows all the FMD required external resources is:

```
    response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/ ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/ unpkg.com/sunburst-chart;"
```

P.S. Note that your code is also broken because the `request` var is undefined in the scope of the `after_request` function.

Comment: Hi @mircealungu ,Thank you for your answer but, I have even tried to comment out the response headers and am still unable to use the Dashboard and facing the same issue and also I am able to print request in after_request  function

Comment: Make sure that you restart the Flask server after you make the changes. If you're not in debug mode they are not visible otherwise. About the request: maybe you have it defined somewhere else in the scope I guess.

Comment: Of course @mircealungu,I have restarted the server before before posting here and even checked it now , but it's the same.

Comment: There's another problem with FMD. If you use CSRFProtect from flask_wtf, and do `CSRFProtect(app)`, then try to login to FMD, you'll get a 400 BAD REQUEST.